# Will Redis return expired keys from an EXISTS call?

Tags: redis

I’m wondering if anyone here can help me confirm how key expiry would work in a particular use case. Our case is that we are using Redis to deduplicate messages in a message delivery system based on a unique identifier used as the key. We are using SETEX to set a TTL and have used GET calls in the past to check expiry, but I’m wondering if an EXISTS call instead of a GET would work just the same. I see in [the documentation](https://redis.io/commands/expire#how-redis-expires-keys) that Redis will passively expire keys “simply when some client tries to access it, and the key is found to be timed out”, which is why we can rely on GET calls to only return a value if the TTL hasn’t passed, but would the same happen for an EXISTS call? To put that another way, will EXISTS calls passively expire a key if it’s past the TTL and return 0, or is it possible that an EXISTS call will not take TTL into consideration, not passively expire a key that we’re calling EXISTS for, and possibly return a 1 even though the key’s TTL has expired?

Answer (score 2):

Yes Redis should passively expire keys on Exists

Comment: Just checking... you mean " should passively expire keys on *EXISTS*"?

Comment: Correct, sorry fixed the typo

Comment: Perhaps this is being too picky, but is there documentation  on this that's more explicit than saying trying to "access" the value? Maybe it's just me but I didn't consider checking the presence of a key as being the same as accessing it (or the value).

Answer (score 0):

I wondered the same thing and couldn't find anything explicit, so I looked at the source code for Redis: https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/4cae99e785ee3302adc37144f07f737b9b7bfc7d/src/db.c#L767.

The function `existsCommand` calls `lookupKeyReadWithFlags`, which calls `lookupKey`, whose documentation states that one of its side effects is that "A key gets expired if it reached its TTL."